# Alternate to "`--whole-archive`" in bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

I want to link an external static lib in one of my bazel based c++ project. I need "`whole-archive`" option for linking the library like gcc or g++ build:

```
g++ main.cc -Wl,--whole-archive -lhttp -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Can anybody suggest what is the alternate to "`--whole-archive`" in bazel?

Comment: `bazel` is build system; what tool chain are you using with it?

Comment: using c++ tool chain

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, alwayslink doesn't work with precompiled libraries, only with `cc_library` compiled and linked by Bazel. There is one undocumented hack (I guess I'm just documenting it by mentioning it here), and it's to rename .a file to .lo file. Then Bazel will link it as whole archive.

Beware that this is a hack, and will stop working without warning. We have plans for some variation of `cc_import` rule exactly for this use case, to import a precompiled binary into the workspace with the ability to set whole archiveness on it. It's just not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.alwayslink

> alwayslink
>
> Boolean; optional; nonconfigurable; default is 0
>
> If 1, any binary that depends (directly or indirectly) on this C++
>   library will link in all the object files for the files listed in
>   srcs, even if some contain no symbols referenced by the binary. This
>   is useful if your code isn't explicitly called by code in the binary,
>   e.g., if your code registers to receive some callback provided by some
>   service.