# Bazel failed to include a external static library .a

Tags: include, static-libraries, bazel

**-- Question solved --**

This question is solved. Thanks for all the help!

The problem and the reason is briefly stated as following for other readers in the future:

**[Environment]**

Ubuntu 14.04, Bazel, C++

**[Question]**

I want to include an external library. So I download the source file and make it as as a static lib .a.

I correctly set the BUILD, WORKSPACE and related files. However, when compile, it alerts the error:

```
Linking of rule '//main' failed (Exit 1)
main: error: undefined reference to 'void ex_lib::compute(double*, double const*, double const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried with the .lo and alwayslink method here but doesn't work.

[Alternate to "`--whole-archive`" in bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674163/alternate-to-whole-archive-in-bazel)

**[Reason]**

It is because that the external library source files contains duplicate header files. So I fix the header file problem. Make the .a again. Then everything works.

So nothing wrong with the bazel. It is the library itself that cause the problem. But the error information is confusing and I think it is caused by bazel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is solved. Special thanks to mhlopko.

It is mainly because there is errors with the lib source file. Thus .a file I use contains errors. Now the bazel works fine with the new lib file.

By the way, now bazel works fine with both .a or .so file that I generated.

Comment: maybe you can directly update your question post with this update, it is easier for readers to have all the elements at the same place :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As this problem is actually  caused by the library I use, instead of bazel, I'm going to close or delete this post to avoid misleading.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do to investigate further is to run the clean bazel build with `--subcommands` to see individual command lines of actions executed. Then you can `cd` into the sandbox, and execute the same `gcc` command as bazel does and debug what's wrong. Or you can try to get linking to work by handwriting gcc command, and pasting here both the command bazel generated, and your desired command. Is it possible that you have multiple `liegroups` libs installed on the system and gcc is getting one that's incompatible with headers you're including?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I do generate several liegroups lib during the test. But it still shows "undefined reference to " after cleaning up and being left with only one liegroups lib.

Comment: How does the gcc command link command look like (including params file)?

Comment: Thank you mhlopko. The problem is solved. This is because there is defect with the lib source file but it could compile. Now bazel works fine with the new generated lib file.